# C++ use RAII objects with comma operator?

Tags: c++, concurrency, lifetime

I have a lock class like this:

```cpp
class Mutex {
  Guard lock();  // acquire the lock
}
class Guard {
  ~Guard();  // release the lock
}
```

This is how I'm using it now:

```cpp
Mutex m_mutex;
T m_data;

T get_data() {
  auto guard = m_mutex.lock();
  return m_data;
}
```

But I'm thinking is it safe / good practice to write like this?

```cpp
T get_data() {
  return (m_mutex.lock(), m_data);
}
```

Comment: The `lock` function returns an object by value. That means it might be copied. If it's copied then that means you will have two `Guard` objects.  Think about what happens if one of them gets destructed, but not the other. What happens with the actual lock? Unless this is a school (or similar) assignment or exercise, please don't try to create your own locking or synchronization primitives, it's *extremely* hard to get them right.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Guard` doesn't have copy constructor. It is moved on return.

Comment: the comma operator is somewhat obscure. Not everybody actually knows how it works (and usually thats ok). Using the comma operator when not needed, but  merely to safe a line of code is not good practice imho

Comment: Have you explicitly marked the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operators as `delete`? Without a proper [mre] it's too easy to get bogged down in possibly irrelevant details.

Comment: don't try to be too clever. If the code you are using now is ok then there is no reason to change it, or is there?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Guard` is just a wrapper of `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`. It doesn't have copy constructor because `std::unique_lock` doesn't.

Comment: Regarding [the comma expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), the object returned by `m_mutex.lock()` will be kept alive until the end of the containing expression, so it should not be destructed until the copy of `m_data` has been made. So *probably* safe. But good practice? No not really. It's hard to read, understand, and the issue of sequencing and life-time makes it hard for most programmers to be sure it's the right thing. And all of that will also make it harder to maintain.

Comment: Just use `std::scoped_lock` or `std::unique_lock`. In general don't be "smart" by overloading operators (to unexcepted/surprising behavior), and NEVER touch the comma operator. So write `T get_data() { std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{m_mutex}; return m_data; }` that will surprise no-one

Comment: My first thought was that you misspelled the guard (that you intended `return (std::scoped_lock(mutex), foo);`). Then I was pointed to the fact that you have a custom `lock()`. The trick itself is ok-ish, but assigning unconventional meaning to `.lock()` is probably not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The name is inspired by Rust. `mutex.lock()` returns `LockResult<MutexGuard<T>>` in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mostly safe.

The order of destruction has been clarified with [CWG 1885](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1885.html), so that the temporary object materialized from the `m_mutex.lock()` call will be destroyed only after the result object of the function has been initialized.

The built-in comma operator also guarantees that the left-hand operand is sequenced before the right-hand one.

There is however a problem if there is a `operator,` overload for `T`. In that case the expression could have any effect. To avoid issues with that you need to explicitly cast the lock expression to `void`, which forces use of the built-in comma operator:

```
return ((void)m_mutex.lock(), m_data);
```

---

Whether this is good practice goes into opinion territory, but I think there are definitively going to be many developers who will be confused by this construct for a moment (even if they know how the comma operator and lifetimes work) and it doesn't really save you anything. (Having to choose an unused name is annoying, but not a real issue.)

Comment: I agree with this answer in the context of a return. In other contexts, it's less clear. For example, if `m_data` has a copy constructor but no assignment operators and a local variable needs to be populated and outlive the lock, things get more awkward. All of the ways I know to accomplish that are less than ideal for one reason or another. A getter method or this comma trick seem cleaner than most.